# Python - PrettyTable - Nothing Works

Tags: python, prettytable

I feel like a complete idiot at the moment. I'm trying to populate data from a dataframe into prettytable for display. The reason I don't want to use pandas directly, is that it seems like a giant PITA to get number formatting specific to each column... which I know is easy in prettytable.

While I've used this package before... it just straight up isn't working.

```
a = PrettyTable
a.add_column("test",[1, 2])

TypeError: add_column() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'
```

I've tried adding by row

```
a = PrettyTable
a.add_row("test",[1, 2])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_field_names'
```

And then adding the field names

```
a = PrettyTable
a.field_names = ["1","2","3"]
a.add_row("test",[1, 2])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_field_names'
```

I'm using the latest version, installed via pip, v3.3.0. I'm running python v3.9.6 through Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: You forgot the parentheses on the end of the class call.  `a = PrettyTable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to get an instance of the class:

```py
a = PrettyTable()
a.add_column("test",[1, 2])
```

If you forget them, it references the class.

See this example:

```py
class Foo:
    def method(self, *args):
        print(args)

Foo.method(1, 2, 3) # (2, 3)
Foo().method(1, 2, 3) # (1, 2, 3)
```

If you use the class, the first parameter is passed as `self`.

If you use the instance, the instance is automatically passed as `self`.